# Unable to get CentOS v7 to boot on Dell after switching from MBR to UEFI

Tags: uefi, centos-7, dell-precision

I had an older Dell system booting via MBR that died so I moved sda to a newer Dell system and tried to setup uefi boot. I get "No bootable devices found" by the Dell BIOS when I try to boot of the entry that I created.

Since the system has a 2nd disk, I temporarily disconnected sda and installed CentOS v7 to sdb and it worked. I'm able to boot of sdb - even after I reconnected sda.

So then I recreated the sda efi filesystem from FAT32 to FAT16 since that was the CentOS installer created on sda efi partition - and I copied over all the files from sdb boot/efi to sda boot/efi. 
But still I can't boot off of sda.

**I don't want to have to re-install CentOS on sda.**
What do I need to do to get the Dell BIOS to boot of the efi entry that I created?

Here is the current efibootmgr output:

```
efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0005,0001,0002,0000
Boot0000  Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,8e1549f6-8d27-4875-9395-0f045305a79d,0x800,0x4b000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}....................
Boot0001* CentOS        HD(1,GPT,85ecf60a-9298-458c-8abb-3a31dacca6a8,0x800,0x64000)/File(\EFI\centos\shimx64.efi)
Boot0002* fbx64 HD(1,GPT,2c34da76-532b-4c4c-8202-7d0eb71550c0,0x800,0xf4800)/File(\EFI\BOOT\fbx64.efi)
Boot0005* grub  HD(1,GPT,2c34da76-532b-4c4c-8202-7d0eb71550c0,0x800,0xf4800)/File(\EFI\centos\shimx64.efi)
```

The bottom two efi entries are the ones that I created. The CentOS entry is what the CentOS installer created.

What is weird is that when I reconnected sda that I can still boot CentOS off of sdb.

Other details:

- boot mode is UEFI
- secure boot: OFF
- BIOS disk mode as ACHI
- sda is partitioned via GPT

In the BIOS boot screen, I can see the entries I created with efibootmgr for starting CentOS.

sda partition info:

```
 parted /dev/sda
 GNU Parted 3.1                                                                                                 
 Using /dev/sda                                                                                                 
 Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.                                                 
 (parted) print
 Model: ATA HGST HDN726040AL (scsi)                                                                             
 Disk /dev/sda: 4001GB                                                                                          
 Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B                                                                     
 Partition Table: gpt                                                                                           
 Disk Flags: pmbr_boot                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags                                                       
 1      1049kB  514MB   513MB   fat16        efi   boot                                                        
 3      514MB   8513MB  8000MB  ext4
 4      8513MB  8713MB  199MB   fat32        efi   boot
 6      8713MB  10.5GB  1800MB               swap
 5      10.5GB  4001GB  3990GB  xfs
```

Yes, I know that there is a 2nd efi partition at partition 4.  Initially, I created that partition out of the old swap partition but then figured that Dell may not like the efi partition at sda4. So I converted the old /boot partition to efi (I saved all the kernel images, etc and copied them to /boot on the root partition) and setup sda1 to mount at /boot/efi.

Comment: Can you access the files through [EFI Shell](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#UEFI_Shell)? Can you directly start the 'correct' shimx64.efi through it?

Comment: Thanks for answering. This is a desktop so the BIOS doesn't have an EFI shell. I'll see if I can set one up as another boot entry. I don't think I've tried to start the shim.efi on sda - I'll try that.

Comment: I tried to start the shimx64.efi on sda - but it didn't work either. What is fallbak/fbx64.efi supposed to do? The one on sda won't boot (same error) and the one on sdb just causes the screen to flicker and then go back to the BIOS boot menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran out of time trying to fix the UEFI boot so I ended up just reinstalling CentOS v7 on the transferred OS disk, and then re-configuring it back to the way it was (I saved /etc/). So far, re-configuring the base functionality I need has taken less time than I spent trying to get the UEFI boot issue fixed - but I don't have all things back up and running.

@user1686 - thanks for responding.